# Integration as inverse of differentiation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have been reading "Mathematical Methods of Physics and Engineering" By K. F. Riley, M. P. Hobson and S. J. Bence. In chapter $2$  of this book (Preliminary Calculus) Under the sub-topic $2.2.2$ "Integration as the inverse of differentiation", I'm having trouble understanding the following proof:

> $$ \text{Let } F(x)=\int_a^xf(u) \mathrm{d}u \ .\text{We then have:}$$
> \begin{align}
>  F(x+\Delta x)&=\int_a^{x+\Delta x}\ f(u) \mathrm{d}u\\[1ex]
>               &=\int_a^x f(u)\ \mathrm{d}u\ + \ \int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(u)\ \mathrm{d}u\\[1ex]
>  F(x+\Delta x)&= F(x)+\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(u)\  \mathrm{d}u\\[1ex]
> \implies\frac{F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)}{\Delta x}&=\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_x^{x+\Delta x}f(u) \ \mathrm{d}u
> \end{align}
> Letting $\Delta x \to 0$ the LHS becomes $\frac{\mathrm{d}F}{\mathrm{d}x}$ whereas the RHS becomes $f(x)$. The latter conclusion follows because when $\Delta x$ is small the value of the integral on the RHS approximately becomes $f(x)\Delta x$, and in the limit $\Delta x \to 0$ no approximation is involved.

I didn't understand the last statement. How did we approximate the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is supposed to be continuous the values of $f(y)$ for $x <y<x+\Delta x$ are all close to $f(x)$. So we can approximate $\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(y)dy$ by $\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(x)dy$ (in which the integrand is a  constant as far as integration w.r.t. $y$ is concerned) and the value of this integral $f(x)\Delta x$.